# Expected number of word appearances inside a long string

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I've got very similar question to this: [Finding the expected value in the given problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638790/finding-the-expected-value-in-the-given-problem/1638816?newreg=e03c0d10423c4170a4ecc5c1e8428300)

> It is given that a monkey types on a 26-letter keyboard with all the
> keys as lowercase English alphabets. Each letter is chosen
> independently and uniformly at random. If the monkey types 1,000,000
> letters, what is the expected number of times the sequence "proof"
> appears?

But with one little change, that can make a difference - we consider word `socks` instead of `proof` (the first letter and the last one are the same).

Are the events "`socks` begins at 1 sign" and "`socks` begins at 5 sign" independent? For me, if `socks` begins at 1 sign, it can change probability of the latter event, because the first letter of event that begins at 5 sign is already chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linearity of the expectation to solve this problem, which doesn't require an independence condition. You are correct that "`socks` begins at the first character" and "`socks` begins at the fifth character" are NOT independent events.

Let $X$ be a random variable denoting the number of occurrences of "proof" in our text.

For $1 \leq i \leq 999996$, let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable that equals $1$ provided that the word "proof" starts at the $i^{\text{th}}$ character and equals $0$ otherwise.

We have $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = P(X_{i} = 1) = 1/26^5$ since it's just the probability of getting a fixed character $5$ times in a row.

Thus,

$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i} X_i\right] = \sum_{i} \mathbb{E}[X_i] = \frac{999996}{26^5}.$$